# is jsp a good choice to make server side coding?

Tags: java, jsp, client, swt

i am doing a client-server Application.The client software is a GUI which is made using SWT.Now my question is "Is JSP a good choice to develop the server side coding?". Please give some suggestions..

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSP is a layer on top of servlets and is intended for writing HTML pages. In a client server application you probably have your own protocol (JSON, XML, binary ...). You can communicate via HTTP simply by using a servlet.

Answer (score 1):

JSP can allow to do some logic in jsp by using Scriptlets.
But it is not good practice.In case of client -server application ,you can use client as jsp page and user servlet for server side code .From your jsp page you can call servlet where you can implement your logic.